# open KNOWNFOLDERID with askopenfilename in Tkinter / Python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, filepath

I want to set my initialdir to a KNOWNFOLDERID like Documents or Desktop.
Is this even possible?
I tried like this, but instead it open up the directory of my python project.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir="%USERPROFILE%/Documents",
    title="get a file",
    filetypes=((".jpg files", "*.jpg"), (".png files", "*.png")) 
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `import os; print(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents"))`. But there are instances of it failing if the user has changed the location of their documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pathlib's `home` if you just need the user's directory.

To get the path of the documents folder use

```
from pathlib import Path

docs_folder = Path.home() / "Documents"
```

This will work both on Windows and Unix based OS.

Alternatively you can use `expandvars` from os.path

```
import os
docs_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expandvars('%USERPROFILE%'),'Documents')
```

Comment: Excellent, both methods give me my desired result. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, using `Path.home()` from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home) you get the enviroment string `%USERPROFILE%`, but the path of the Documents folder may not be `%USERPROFILE%\Documents`, since its location is editable by the user.

If the KnownFolderID has an equivalent [CLSID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl), you can use the [SHGetFolderPathW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) function with the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library.
For example, to get the Documents folder path:

```
import ctypes

ptr = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(None, 5, None, 0, ptr)
folder_path = ptr.value
```

The second argument is the CLSID [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-8.0). For example Documents = 5, Desktop = 16, UserProfile = 40.
The third parameter is if you want the folder current path (0) or the folder default path (1).

With ctypes it should be also possible to retrieve the path of the other [KnownFolderID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) (those that don't have a clsid equivalent) defining a structure, and that would answer this question completely. If I manage to do it, I'll update this reply.